# Way to have a theme-settings form input to accept numbers only?

Tags: 7, forms

I am creating some theme settings and am creating a form to populate them in `theme-settings.php`. I am using the hook `hook_form_system_theme_settings_alter()`.

I would like to restrict or verify that only numbers can be entered into a field. I've searched online but have not found how to do this. Would anyone know what I ought to add to my code?

Code currently looks like:

```
$form['mysite_theme']['mysite_contact_phone'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Contact Number'),
    '#default_value' => $default['mysite_contact_phone'],
    '#description' => t('Enter the main contact number for this site.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to add your own validation handler. After the code you've shown, add this:

```
$form['#validate'][] = 'my_validation_handler';
```

Then in your handler, you can add your own validation:

```
function my_validation_handler($form, &$form_state)
{
  if(!is_numeric($form_state['values']['mysite_contact_phone']))
  {
    form_set_error('mysite_contact_phone', t('Contact number must be numeric'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I was almost about to close this as I found `'#element_validate' => array('element_validate_number'),` but only just relised this wont allow spaces.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having difficulty getting this to work. I'll close this and create a new ticket.

Comment: You mean you want to allow numbers and spaces?

Comment: Eventually, yes, but I want to try to get it working with just numbers first (currently with the above nothing happens).

Comment: There is a good chance that the value is not stored in `$form_state['values']'mysite_contact_phone']`. Many admin forms in Drupal have the value nested deeper, so you should dump the entire $form_state['values'] variable to find the actual location of the submitted data.

Comment: Ah, this seems to be under `$form_state['input']['mysite_theme']['mysite_contact_phone']`

Comment: Are you sure it's not in $form_state['values']? I believe $form_state['input'] values are not sanitized.

Comment: There appears to be no `value` array.

Comment: values, not value.

Comment: Oops, typo - yes no value or values. Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/qlQdTmT.png this is from using `dpm($form_state);`

Comment: That's odd. Really odd. That's almost worth starting a thread about - the values element is a fundamental element in Drupal forms. I've never seen it not be present. I wonder if it's something specific to theme settings forms.

Comment: hey so I think I know why this is occurring. The dpm() needed to be in the submit hook, where's I was working on the form alter hook, so the values array had not been created.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it.

Comment: Thanks for you're help :) Haha now I gotta figure out why the error message is not displaying!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Elements module](https://www.drupal.org/project/elements) to get a HTML5 number field.